# Encapsulationg strings in an enum c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api

I'm new to C# and i'm trying to encapsulate certain states in an enum and trying to add them to a list but I am getting an error `missing ;`

Here is what I have coded out:

```
namespace abc.Models
{

    public enum GroupState
    {
        FINISHED,
        SKIPPED,
        ERROR     
    }

    public static class GroupStates
    {
        public static List<GroupState> TerminalStates = new List<GroupState>{
            GroupState.FINISHED, GroupState.SKIPPED, GroupState.ERROR
        }
    }
}
```

I intend to use these states in my controller file. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to punt a semicolon at the end of the line where you instantiate the List `public static List<GroupState> TerminalStates = new List<GroupState>{GroupState.FINISHED, GroupState.SKIPPED, GroupState.ERROR }` **;**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a semicolon `;` after the statement

```
       public static List<GroupState> TerminalStates = new List<GroupState>{
                    GroupState.FINISHED, GroupState.SKIPPED, GroupState.ERROR
                }
```

and `"ERROR"` is not in your enum `"GroupState"` it is `ERROR3`. Both changes need to be added:

Code snippet will be like:

```
        public static class GroupStates
        {
            public static List<GroupState> TerminalStates = new List<GroupState>{
                GroupState.FINISHED, GroupState.SKIPPED, GroupState.ERROR3
            };
        }
```

Comment: Yes this works. Also, how would I access TerminalStates (FINISHED, SKIPPED and GROUPED) in my controller?

Comment: can you try this, am not sure what you expecting here: abc.GroupStates.TerminalStates[0] this will Return "Finished"

Comment: I tried this too and got the expected values. Thanks.